# How does one take a screenshot of an AUT using HP UFT natively?

Tags: vbscript, hp-uft, webpage-screenshot

I have never used HP UFT and I would like to know how to take a screenshot of the current state of the application during a test.

The AUT is a web application and I'd like to take a screenshot of different events during the test running.

I would like to save these screenshots to a specific folder structure on the host computer.

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR**

```
Browser("micclass:=Browser").Page("micclass:=Page").CaptureBitmap "C:\Temp\TA Framework\Data\Screenshots\WebPortal.png", True
```

You can use CaptureBitmap command on a Page to take a screenshot. Make sure the folder path exists before executing the command. It will not create the folder structure for you.

resource: [How to capture application screenshot and display it in test results](http://www.automationrepository.com/2011/11/how-to-capture-application-screenshot-using-qtp/)